# Stop Google search personalization keeping search history

Tags: google-search, google-search-history

I know I can stop Google search personalization by not logging in or clearing web history. What I want to do is to keep my search history, but stop Google to personalize my search query. Because I want to keep track of sites I have visited before. The only way found to stop personalization also stops recording search history, visited pages.

So how can I stop search personalization keeping search history?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do this. However, using search history to keep track of what websites you visit is like installing CCTV in your bedroom to keep track of your socks. Your browser is likely equipped with a history function and cloud sync to make sure you don't lose it.